# Sorting barplot in altair by multiple columns

Tags: python, altair

I am trying to sort a dataframe by multiple columns (more precisely, the first column is a string and should be sorted alphabetically and the second column is numeric and should be sorted from lowest to highest).

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "unique_ID": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"],
        "group": ["Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 3", "Group 3", "Group 3", "Group 2"],
        "value": [20, 10, 30, 50, 40, 60]
    }
)
df

alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    y="unique_ID",
    x="value",
    color="group",
)
```

(I would like to upload the result I am currently getting, but the image upload is failing, I will edit the post as soon as I can upload)

What I would like to achieve is to sort this barplot by two variables, first alphabetically by group (i.e. Group 1, Group 2, Group 3) and second, by value from lowest to highest.

The order I would like to achieve is b - a - f - c - e - d (I hope I did not make any mistake here).

Note: Of course, this is just a simple example in order to understand how to sort by multiple variables. I understand that I can sort via `EncodingSortField`

e.g.

```py
y=alt.Y(
  "unique_ID",
  sort=alt.EncodingSortField(field="group", op="min")
)
```

but as far as I know, this only works for one column.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to compute a combined label as per https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/7017

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "unique_ID": ["f", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a"],
        "group": ["Group1", "Group1", "Group3", "Group3", "Group3", "Group2"],
        "value": [20, 10, 30, 50, 40, 60]
    }
)
df

alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().transform_calculate(
    sort_field='datum.group + datum.unique_ID'
).encode(
    y=alt.Y("unique_ID:N").sort(field='sort_field', op='min'),
    x="value",
    color="group",
)
```

I'm unsure why `op='min'` is needed here and the default 'average' is not working.

Comment: This is great, thank you. What would I need to modify if I would like to sort the second variable from highest to lowest?

Comment: Maybe I overread it, but how does this line `sort_field='datum.group + datum.unique_ID'` ensure, that the sorting by the second variable by occurs by value (increasing or decreasing)?

Comment: @Revan For your first question, you can set  the `order` param like shown here https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.EncodingSortField.html. For your second question, the transforms just joins the fields together into one string that is then sorted alphabetically (Grou2c, Group2d, etc)